# How to detect property changed when refreshing entities with EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, inotifypropertychanged

$Hello_all,

a simple question, in a project I want to raise the property changed events on model classes. The model classes are loaded and refreshed using Entity Framework (`ObjectContext.Refresh()`).

Is possible to modify the EF generated properties to include the code that handles the raise of the propertychanged event?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify the class generator. Default `EntityObject` based entities already implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. If you are using POCO entities (and POCO T4 generator or DbContext T4 generator) you simply have to modify T4 file to generate properties with a code raising the event.